# How to parse xml data in Retrofit 2.1?

Tags: android, xml, retrofit2

I am new to Retrofit 2.1 and trying to parse XML data given below.
This tutorial was helpful to me but failed to resolve data at my own
[How to Integrate XML Converter Tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-integrate-xml-converter)

XML DATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE TSeqSet PUBLIC "-/.......">

<TSeqSet>
<TSeq>
    <TSeq_length>377</TSeq_length>
</TSeqSet>
```

POJO Class

```
@Root(name = "TSeq")
public class TSeq {

    @Element(name = "TSeq_length")
    private long TSeq_length;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String link;

    public TSeq() {}
}
```

JAVA CLASS Implementaion Detail

```
 private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
private static Retrofit builder;

 interface GitHubClient {
        @Headers({
                "Content-Type: application/xml"
        })
        @GET("efetch.fcgi")
        Call<TSeq> getNews(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options );
    }

     // making retrofit for xml data handle
                builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(All_Constants.CommonUrl)
                        .client(new OkHttpClient())
                        .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();



// prepare dynamic part or URI
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("id","749778981");


    GitHubClient service = builder.create(GitHubClient.class);
            TSeq user1 = null;
            try {
                user1 = service.getNews(data).execute().body();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("* * * User 1: ",user1.toString());
```

Please help me to fetch XML data via Retrofit2.1 Lib.

Thankyou everyone